# Return only ALL CAPS strings in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Pretty simple question, specific to BigQuery. I'm sure there's a command I'm missing. I'm used to using "collate" in another query which doesn't work here.

```
     email           
| --------           |
| eric@email.com     | 
| JOHN@EMAIL.COM     | 
| STACY@EMAIL.COM    | 
| tanya@email.com    |
```

Desired return:

JOHN@EMAIL.COM,STACY@EMAIL.COM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *
from your_table
where upper(email) = email
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case you want the output as a comma separated list - use below

```
select string_agg(email) emails
from your_table
where upper(email) = email
```

with output

[image]

You can use below cte (which is exact data sample from your question) for testing purposes

```
with your_table as (
  select 'eric@email.com' email union all
  select 'JOHN@EMAIL.COM' union all
  select 'STACY@EMAIL.COM' union all
  select 'tanya@email.com' 
)
```

Comment: for some reason this results in a blank value

Comment: any update? still empty? no way! try with sample data from your question - I added it to answer

Comment: so, did you have chance to try? does it work for you now?

Comment: Hey! Sorry! This worked!

Comment: Time for me to read your book ;)